# Django jQuery Ajax. I get response, but it does not insert in html

Tags: ajax, django, jquery

It is enough for me with `dajaxice`. Now I am trying to destroy my brain using jQuery.

Earlier, I was doing `$.get` and all was OK. Now, when i try it with `$.ajax` (get)
this is what i have:

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from BitProject.views import index_page,xhr_test


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^$', index_page),
    url(r'^ajaxrequest/$', xhr_test, name='ajaxurl'),
)
```

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.utils import simplejson


def index_page(request):
    return render_to_response ('template_1.html')

def xhr_test(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        message = "Hello AJAX"
    else:
        message = "Hello"
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(message), mimetype="applicaton/json")
```

template_1.html

```
<html>
    <head>

    {% load staticfiles %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/style_2.css" %}" type="text/css">
    <script src="{% static "js/jquery_v183.js" %}"></script>

    <script>   
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#picture_1').click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url:"/BitProject/ajaxrequest/",
                    type: 'GET',
                    success: function(data){
                        $('#someEl_2').html(data)
                    },
                    dataType: JSON
                });
            });
        });


    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <img src="{% static "images/sunny.png" %}" id="picture_1" magrin='10px'/>
        <div id="someEl_2">First Text</div>
        </div>
    <body>
</html>
```

I am using chrome. I see in console that I have response - in response tab - `Hello AJAX`. but nothing happens on the page. where is my problem?

Comment: yes i know about csrf(and steel cant use it) but in my experiment with $.get all works without any csrf tools

Comment: `JSON` should be `'json'` (a string). Add an error callback to your $.ajax so that you can see what is causing it to fail. When it works, you should expect to see `[object Object]` in your page.

Comment: what happens when you do a `console.log('data')` in `success` method? you may want to try `success: function(status, data, xhr)` instead of `success: function(data)`. Also, just make `JSON` -> `'json'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you put the `dataType` in javascript between quotes, change:

```
dataType: JSON
```

to

```
dataType: 'json'
```

What does your browser do when you access `/BitProject/ajaxrequest/` directly?

Answer (score 0):

You also have a typo in the `view's` code. Replace:

> mimetype="**applicaton**/json"

for:

> mimetype="**application**/json"